# How to properly defined Post route with provider and processor Api Platform 3.0

Tags: php, api, symfony, backend, api-platform.com

We have a backend where ressources and entity are appart,
Currently we are on Api Platform 2.6 and after an update and a use of

> php bin/console api:upgrade-resource

we are on 2.7 ( goal is 3.0)

the problem is the gestion of subresources Post request with provider, processor and controller.
It's for create a subresources.

For exemple this route (defined inside of Basket resource) :

```
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/clients/{id}/baskets.{_format}',
    processor: BasketDataPersister::class,
    provider : ClientDataProvider::class,
    status: 200,
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write', 'write:Basket']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read', 'read:Basket']],
    operations: [
        new Post(controller: PostClientBasketController::class, normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read', 'read:Basket']], denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write', 'write:Basket']], security: 'is_granted(\'ROLE_USER\')', requirements: ['id' => '^[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$']),
    ],
)]
```

The controller need an instance of Client resource to work

```
public function __invoke(Client $data, Request $request, ?string $_format): Basket|JsonResponse
{
/** @var Basket $basket */
        $basket = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), Basket::class, $_format);
        $basket
            ->setClient($data->getId())
            ->setOrganizationId($data->getOrganizationId())
        ;

        return $basket;
}
```

How to get the Client for this request and send it to controller, etc. ?

I also try to link uriVariables like that :

```
uriVariables: ['id' => new Link(
        fromClass: \App\Resource\Client::class,
        identifiers: ['id']
    )],
```

not working too...

Comment: I think if you use a custom `provider`, the `uriVariable` is not read at all. You should handle it in your provider manually by using the `$uriVariable` argument in the `process()` method. Something like this `$this->entityManager->getRepository(Client::class)->find($uriVariable['id'])->getBasket()`. But I don't exactly know how it would work with a controller (API-Platform doesn't recommended it).